# how to create available resources

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I want to create simple site that allow to upload sound tracks , and I can play it from every where , the idea is

- create uploader with silverlight --> Done
- display them Done

I want to create Rss for its title and link to it

do I need a ftp folder on my server , so that I can play them , or any other idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need an FTP folder, just link to the resource via HTTP in the RSS feed. In other words, either link the title or text in the description to a real URL:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/audio/filename.wav
```

Comment: do u mean to add a folder at my project for example audio and upload to it right

Comment: @AMH, that's correct. It's as simple as upload to that folder and link to it to play. The browser will handle the rest.